# simple form validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

i have very simple basic form in HTML and i want to validate the form using jquery..

i tried using bassistance.de validation plugins but did not work

```
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="0">
<tr>
  <td align="right">First Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" class=" text hasCorners"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Last Name</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="LastName" class=" text hasCorners"></></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">EMail</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Email" class=" text hasCorners"></></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Phone</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="Phone" class=" text hasCorners"></></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Address</td>
  <td><textarea cols="20" rows="5" name="Address" class=" text hasCorners"></></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right">Country</td>
  <td>
  <SELECT name="Country" class=" text hasCorners"></>
    <option value="" selected>[choose yours]
    <option value="008">Albania
    <option value="012">Algeria
    <option value="016">American Samoa
    <option value="020">Andorra
    <option value="024">Angola
    <option value="660">Anguilla
    <option value="010">Antarctica
    <option value="028">Antigua And Barbuda
    <option value="032">Argentina
    <option value="051">Armenia
    <option value="533">Aruba 
 </SELECT>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="right"></td>
  <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The jquery validate plugin from bassistance.de works great.  If you include your implementation of the plugin with your code, perhaps we can see why it is not working properly.

Comment: On another note, I don't actually even see a form tag in your code sample.  And jquery validate plugin was designed to use label tags to highlight fields that are invalid, so unless you specify another container object you wouldn't see which fields are invalid, it would simply block your submission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been using for a while the [JQuery Yab plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery_yav), take a look, it is nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
Have a look and try this
==============
<html>
<head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"> 
</script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class ="container">
<h3 class = "text-center">Sample Form to be validate</h3>
<div class = "col-lg-8 m-auto d-block">
<form action = "www.sjflksdf.com" id = "myform">
<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "user">UserName</label>
<input type = "text" id = "username" name = "username" class = "form-control" 
autocomplete = "off">
<h5 id = "usermessage"></h5>
</div>
<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "password">Password</label>
<input type = "text" id = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control">
<h5 id = "passwordmessage"></h5>
</div>
<div class = "form-group">
<label for = "conpassword">Confirm Password</label>
<input type = "text" id = "conpassword" name = "conpassword" class = "form-control">
<h5 id = "conpasswordmessage"></h5>
</div>
<div class = "form-group">
<input type = "submit" id = "btnsubmit" value = "Submit" name = "btnsubmit" class = 
"btn btn-primary" >
</div>
</form>

</div>

</div>
</body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
debugger
$('#usermessage').hide();
$('#passwordmessage').hide();
$('#conpasswordmessage').hide();

var user_err = true;
var pass_err = true;
var conpass_err = true;

$('#username').keyup(function(){
    user_check();
});
$('#password').keyup(function(){
    pass_check();
});
$('#conpassword').keyup(function(){
    pass_compair();
});


function pass_check()
    {
    var pass_value = $('#password').val();
    if(pass_value.length == '' || pass_value.length <= 6){
    $('#passwordmessage').show();
    $('#passwordmessage').html("**please fill out password having length > 6");
    $('#passwordmessage').focus();
    $('#passwordmessage').css ("color","red");
        conpass_err = false;
        return false;
        }else{
        $('#passwordmessage').hide();
        }
    }
function pass_compair()
    {
        var pass_value = $('#password').val();
        var passcompair_value = $('#conpassword').val();
        if(pass_value != passcompair_value){
            $('#conpasswordmessage').show();
            $('#conpasswordmessage').html("** Repeat password not matched");
            $('#conpasswordmessage').focus();
            $('#conpasswordmessage').css ("color","red");
            pass_err = false;
            return false;
            }else{
                $('#conpasswordmessage').hide();
                }
    }
function user_check()
    {
    var user_val = $('#username').val();
    if( user_val.length == ''){
        $('#usermessage').show();
        $('#usermessage').html("** Please fill out the UserName");
        $('#usermessage').focus();
        $('#usermessage').css ("color","red");
        user_err = false;
        return false;
            }else{
            $('#usermessage').hide();
            }
    }


    $('#btnsubmit').click(function(){
    user_err = true;
    pass_err = true;
    conpass_err = true;
    debugger

    user_check();
    pass_check();
    pass_compair();

    if((user_err = true) && (user_err = true) && (user_err = true))
        {
         //console.log($('#password').val());

         // ajax post data here...
        return true;
        }else 
        {
        return false;
        }


    });
});
</script>
</html>
```